# Using cURL in php to add a comment to an issue in JIRA

Tags: php, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

Inspired by [using CURL in PHP to add an issue in JIRA via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193325/using-curl-in-php-to-add-an-issue-in-jira-via-rest-api) , I tried to add a comment to an issue in JIRA, but I am getting 405 Error

Error:
*Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_HEADER - assumed 'CURL_HEADER'
Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
type Status report
message Method Not Allowed
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).*

My code:

```
<?php  
$handle=curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$data = <<<JSON
{
    "body": "Please Ignore. Test Comment"
}
JSON;
curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>'https://path.to.Jira/rest/api/2/issue/issue-123',
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        //CURLOPT_HTTPGET =>true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURL_HEADER=>false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD=>"username:password"
        //CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>"POST"
    )
);
$result=curl_exec($handle);
$ch_error = curl_error($handle);

if ($ch_error) {
    echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
} else {
    echo $result;
}

curl_close($handle);
?>
```

What could be the possible solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

Although Borislav's answer is directed at the "symptoms" of your issue, **the simple answer** to both the cURL errors the OP is experiencing is the fact that the constant:

`CURL_HEADER` was typed incorrectly... it should be:

`CURLOPT_HEADER`.

All cURL option constants have **CURLOPT-** as a prefix. See [PHP manual - cURL Transfer options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and scroll down for the constants.

Explaining the error trail a bit further:

The first error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_HEADER - assumed 'CURL_HEADER'

means that PHP doesn't recognize `CURL_HEADER`, simply because **it's a typo**.

This has a domino effect onto the `curl_setopt_array()` function. Because the constant above was typed/spelled incorrectly, this entire function failed and returned false, as per PHP manual on **curl_setopt_array()**: *"If an option could not be successfully set, FALSE is immediately returned, ignoring any future options in the options array"*

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values

Seeing how that function returned false, no cURL options were set. But your script continues to execute, without the required information going into the cURL's HTTP request... and BOOM!

> HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed; The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

The JIRA API throws a 405 response at you, because the HTTP request didn't conform to its requirements.

All because 3 letters were missing from the constant: "CURL**OPT**_HEADER"

This is why programming is fun **:D**

Answer (score 0):

The:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_HEADER - assumed 'CURL_HEADER'

means that PHP doesn't recognize CURL_HEADER as a constant. Maybe your version is old? Or you've mistyped it, or it doesn't exist. The:

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values

means that you have a wrong structure of the parameter you pass to `curl_set_opt($param1, $param2)` and the:

> HTTP Status 405 .... Blah, Blah

means exactly what is says: The server is returning [HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6).

Furthermore pure cUrl will cause you a lot of headaches and if you're developing a full-stack application that connects to JIRA it will be hard.
I've personally done a full featured application that connects to (all) JIRA REST endpoints with cUrl and then with [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) which is a library based on cUrl.
Believe me - it will be much more easier to develop and (more importantly) maintain.

So if you have the option to change your approach I encourage you to switch to Guzzle now. ;)

If you're using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) (which you should be doing ;) ), add the following to your `composer.json` file in the project root:

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.1.1"
    }
}
```

Then:

```
composer.phar install
```

PEAR install is also an option:

```
pear -D auto_discover=1 install guzzlephp.org/pear/guzzle
```

And of course you can also just [include the `guzzle.phar`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php).

Check the [Guzzle docs](http://guzzlephp.org/docs.html) for more information.

Cheers!